# Koma scrbook -- oneside, chaptermark on left, sectionmark on right

Tags: koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage

I'm still struggling to use leftmark and rightmark. Seems leftmark = rightmark!

I'm trying to get `chaptermark` printed on left of header, and `sectionmark` on left.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 12pt, parskip=half]{scrbook}

\usepackage[a4paper,
  vmargin=2cm, hmargin=2cm, % page margins
  includehead, includefoot, % Margins calculated include header and footer
  footskip=2em]
{geometry}

\usepackage[footsepline=0.25pt, headsepline=0.25pt, automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

% automark places chapter/section title in header. Also enables placement in footer.
\automark[section]{chapter}

\usepackage{lastpage}

\ohead{\rightmark}

% Footer content
\cfoot{\tiny{Page \thepage \ of  \pageref*{LastPage} \\
\leftmark}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chap One}

\lipsum[1]

\section{Sec One.One}

\lipsum[2-5]

\section{Sec One.Two}

\lipsum[6-10]

\chapter{Chap Two}

\lipsum[11-15]

\end{document}
```

Comment: you have specified `oneside` on the first line so all pages are "left" pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `autooneside=false` to the package options:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 12pt, parskip=half]{scrbook}

\usepackage[
  margin=2cm, % page margins
  includeheadfoot, % Margins calculated include header and footer
  footskip=2em]
{geometry}

\usepackage[
  footsepline=0.25pt, headsepline=0.25pt,
  automark,
  autooneside=false% <- added
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\chead{}
\ohead{\rightmark}

% Footer content
\cfoot{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}\\\leftmark}
\addtokomafont{pagefoot}{\tiny}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chap One}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Sec One.One}
\lipsum[2-5]
\section{Sec One.Two}
\lipsum[6-10]
\chapter{Chap Two}
\lipsum[11-15]
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Or maybe you want:

[image]

```
\usepackage[
  footsepline=0.25pt, headsepline=0.25pt,
  automark,
  autooneside=false% <- added
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\chead{}
\ihead{\leftmark}
\ohead{\rightmark}
```

Comment: Thanks! Hmm, I have a distinct feeling I should learn German and read the original manual.

Comment: I must say, I wished the default value of autooneside wouldn't be true. When I use \automark with an option argument and use \rightmark in the header then I want \rightmark ;-).